# Git: How to signal end of rev-list --stdin input on Windows

Tags: git, git-rev-list

I'm using `git rev-list --stdin` from Windows command prompt. I'm entering `--` followed by some paths, one on each line.

How do I signal to Git that I'm done entering the list of paths? I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but none seem to work as expected.

The documentation doesn't mention it:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list

I found this related question that helps for Unix, but doesn't seem to work on Windows:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input

Comment: Does a blank line work? I.e., just hitting enter twice?

Comment: nope, just keeps inserting new lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can signal the EOF from keyboard in Windows by pressing `Ctrl+Z`, followed by an `Enter` key.
I have used it when I input files from keyboard to a program, and it works for me. I think it will also work here.

Comment: OK, indeed!

    C:\Git>git rev-list head --stdin
    --
    .
    ^Z

seems to work. Thanks!